# How to connect database from root directory?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection

how to connect database from root folder in winform. I have following code,

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="D:\My Work\Programming\ASP\Projects\Jobapp\App_Data\dtbs.mdf";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;
```

and I want as this,

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="~/dtbs.mdf";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;
```

can anyone tell me??

Comment: try to put the `.mdf` file in root directory and see what happens.

Comment: it is in root directory.

Comment: The path `~/dbts.mdf` is the *root of your ASP.NET application* (where your ASP.NET application "lives") - not the root of the actual disk drive

Answer (score 1):

this is the way bros..

```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|dtbs.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True
```